# How to use Binance REST API with Google Sheets using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, rest, google-sheets

I am trying to use the BINANCE restAPI to receive information about my Binance account. Using the code below, I receive a 403 forbidden error. Is there something I am doing wrong?

**API DOCUMENTATION:** https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md

```
var apiKey = "REMOVED";
var secretKey = "REMOVED";
var binance_url = "https://api.binance.com";
var binance_AccountInformation = "/api/v3/account";

function getBinanceBalance(currencyID) {
    var options = {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "X-MBX-APIKEY": apiKey
        },
        muteHttpExceptions: false
    };

    var timeStamp_1 = new Date();
    var timeStamp = Number(timeStamp_1.getTime()).toFixed(0);
    var requestString_1 = binance_url + binance_AccountInformation + "?timestamp=" + timeStamp;
    var signature = generateSignature(requestString_1);
    requestString = requestString_1 + "&recvWindow=5000&signature=" + signature;
    var url = requestString;
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    var json = response.getContentText();
    var data = JSON.parse(json);

}
```

Comment: HTTP 403 means that you do not have permission to make the request you are making. Have you tried hitting a different endpoint? Can you get any data at all from other endpoints?

Comment: First time using this API. According to the documentation: "HTTP 4XX return codes are used for for malformed requests; the issue is on the sender's side."

Comment: correct - the issue is on your side (you are the sender) and `403 Forbidden` is telling you that either your API key is wrong -hence the Forbidden message,- or simply you are not authorized to hit the endpoint you are hitting.

Comment: API key is correct. I was hoping it was just a "malformed request", or some mistake in my code

Comment: Can you show us about ``generateSignature()``? If you can do, please add it to your question. More information helps to think of the solutions.